# How to run new gms Task object synchronously like PendingResult.await?

Tags: google-play-services

I don't see any `await` synchronous api on `com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task`. Am I missing something? I am trying to migrate to use the new *Client classes in Play services. I already designed my code to run in another thread and use `PendingResult.await`. My code was like this:

```
val pendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(TwinkleApplication.instance.gapiClient)
val account = pendingResult.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

I wish to use this, but don't know how to continue.

```
    val signin = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ctx, Global.getGSO())
    val task = signin.silentSignIn()
```

Comment: Are you implementing this on Kotlin ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`Tasks`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) class includes a static `await` method - in Java I'm doing this:

```
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);

Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();

try {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = Tasks.await(task);
    ...
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // task failed
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // an interrupt occurred while waiting for the task to finish
}
```

Comment: It's a static method, so don't try `your_task.await`, like I did. It is written in his answer but I didn't read it well enough: `Tasks.await(task)` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
 suspend fun fetchLastLocation(): Location? {
    Log.e("location", "fetchLastLocation: 1")
    var location: Location? = null
    try {
        val task = providerClient.lastLocation.apply {
            Log.e("location", "fetchLastLocation: 2")
            addOnFailureListener {
                viewAction.value = ViewAction.OnError(it)
            }
            addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.e("location", "fetchLastLocation: 3")
                viewAction.value = ViewAction.OnLocationFetched(it)
                Log.e("location", "fetchLastLocation: 4")
                location = it

            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Tasks.await(task)
        }
    } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
        viewAction.value = ViewAction.OnError(unlikely)
    }

    Log.e("location", "fetchLastLocation: 5")
    return location
}
```

Try using this in a coroutine