# Android battery consumption in case of frequent call of fusedLocationProviderClient lastKnownLocation?

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have this use-case of sending the user's location when I hit a certain API. As this API call is frequent, I want to avoid the battery consumption of the app.

I am okay with using the lastKnownLocation of the user and sending the same.

```
fun getLastLocation(): Single<LocationUpdate> {
    return Single.create { emitter ->
        fusedLocationproviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                emitter.onSuccess(LocationUpdate.Valid(location.lat, location.long))
            } else {
                emitter.onSuccess(LocationUpdate.UnKnown)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
                emitter.tryOnError(it)
       }
    }
}
```

This function getLastLocation can get called many times, and I read that `fusedLocationproviderClient.lastLocation` is battery efficient and doesn't make a new API call every time and relies on other apps to get the location.

Wanted to understand and know, if it's okay to use this `getLastLocation` call frequently in the app and it's battery efficient or I should think of another way like cache it and set the expiry time to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastLocation is just a cached location like you said so yes it is ok to use as long as you understand what it is which it sounds like you do

Comment: Thanks for the respone. I read the doc, so it wont make a new API call and relies on other apps and maintains the cache at it's end. So, no matter how many time I call this lastLocation, it won't have affect on battery? And I also believe its an async call.

Comment: The main battery drain is the actual GPS chip not the call, last location does not use the actual GPS

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense, one last query if you can answer, how accurate is this cached data and I know there are ways to make it sync instead of async. But would like to have your suggestion on the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by accuracy in this context but its as accurate as the last time an application got a location for. To make synchronous you can use the `Task.await` see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996522/how-to-run-new-gms-task-object-synchronously-like-pendingresult-await